# if i have PyYAML 3.12 its asking for 5.1 and if i install version 5.1 its asking 3.12

Tags: python, machine-learning, failed-installation, incompatibility, chatterbot

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install pyyaml==5.1
Collecting pyyaml==5.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/74/c3e15707516f80192059dde32c9d78f00a88c9f3c4d1efd76cbc8d5b0a20/PyYAML-5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0 has requirement PyYAML<4.0,>=3.12, but you'll have pyyaml 5.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
  Found existing installation: PyYAML 3.13
    Uninstalling PyYAML-3.13:
      Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-3.13
Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\Admin>pip install chatterbot-corpus
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot-corpus in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.2.0)
Collecting PyYAML<4.0,>=3.12 (from chatterbot-corpus)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/96/d02ef8e1f3073e07ffdc240444e5041f403f29c0775f9f1653f18221082f/PyYAML-3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
chatterbot 1.0.5 has requirement pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1, but you'll have pyyaml 3.13 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: PyYAML
  Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.1
    Uninstalling PyYAML-5.1:
      Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-5.1
Successfully installed PyYAML-3.13
```

Comment: You are trying to combine modules that have conflicting requirements. Like the messages are saying: `chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0 has requirement PyYAML<4.0,>=3.12`, and `chatterbot 1.0.5 has requirement pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1` - so it would appear you shouldn't be combining `chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0` with `chatterbot 1.0.5`.

Comment: what should we do in this case:
chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0 has requirement PyYAML<4.0,>=3.12, and chatterbot 1.0.5 has requirement pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `chatterbot_corpus` and not `chatterbot-corpus`, are differents

```
pip install chatterbot_corpus
```

or

```
pip3 install chatterbot_corpus
```